# Android: admob ad at wrong place

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to position my ad banner at bottom of the screen. However, part of the ad is appearing at the top and other part at the bottom. Please take a look at the image below

[wrong ad http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/4390/shot000025.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/4390/shot000025.png)

Below is the code if that helps,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/maingradient"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#00ff00"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:listSelector="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:saveEnabled="true" >

    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="a14fd64cddd4168"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone help please?

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: Can you post your Java code as well?  My guess is you defined an AdView in XML at the bottom (the Saavn Music), and another AdView in Java code that got added at the top, so you have two ads showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your exact problem is, but I see a few issues with your layout.  First, you have a RelativeLayout nested inside another RelativeLayout, but are trying to place it below a third relative layout not contained in the parent? Also, the root RelativeLayout in your file has the `android:orientation` attribute, which is for LinearLayouts.  It's all a bit confusing.

As for a solution, try making the root RelativeLayout a LinearLayout and keeping the vertical orientation.  You can give your nested RelativeLayout a `android:layout_height` of `0dip` and `android:layout_weight` of `1` (and get rid of the `layout_below` attribute, I'm not sure why it's there).  This will put your ListView above the ad, and cause it to fill all the space not taken up by the Ad.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, if all you're doing above the ad is displaying the ListView, there's no need for the nested RelativeLayout.  You can just get rid of it and put the ListView in the LinearLayout directly.  Make sure, if you do this, that you give the ListView the height and weight attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black" >


<com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adUnitId="a14fd64cddd4168"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />


  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/show_locations_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Where is the relatvieLayout1?? android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1